# Wordpress function.php

Tags: wordpress

I make some custom ShortCode in the funtion.php file of a wp theme. The theme is live and working. In the ShortCode i made, i made an error, totally my fault, after saving, the theme dont load, the wp-admin interface dont load either. So i am pretty much screwup with a malfuntion wp theme, and no way to WEB edit the error. By chance, i have a dreamweaver/ftp acces, i download the file, correct the error, and everything is up and running againg

The question : Is it possible to get ONLY ONLINE EDITING, and having a way to get the error, but still have acces to the admin interface to correct it, or your stuck to have an external editor... or force to write PERFECT code first time, every time...

thanks

**N.B. if anybody use and onlie file editor that is fast and easy... no need for code hinting and facy html goodies, just open, edit, save.. that will be fine for me.. any name ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would depend on the particular error.  If the error is affecting the core then it will not let you edit online.  It is good practice to have your files backed up so if something id happen like you are describing you can easily revert back to a back up.  I personally like to edit the files locally and then upload them.  This allows me to have a local back up as well as edit files which have errors.